# Set active true only on current element of the array

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am learning Unity by building a simple card game.

I trying to display one card at the time using random function on the game object array.

I am using UI image component with sprite assets assigned to it while calling DealMyNewCard function on the button component.

I am expecting to see one card displayed at the time while still being able to repeat the process of randomly dealing the card.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class DealCard : MonoBehaviour
{

public GameObject[] dealtCard;
public int cardGenerate;

public void DealMyNewCard(){

   cardGenerate = Random.Range(2, 6);
   dealtCard[cardGenerate].SetActive(!dealtCard[cardGenerate].activeSelf);
  
}
}
```

The issue arises when I reach the top or higher card of the array because it overrides the other hierarchy components of the object and prevents the display of previous cards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My test script :

```
using UnityEngine;

public class DealCard : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] dealtCard;
    public int cardGenerate;

[ContextMenu("Test DealMyNewCard()")] //for inspector test use
public void DealMyNewCard()
{
    cardGenerate = Random.Range(1, dealtCard.Length);
    HideAllCards();
    dealtCard[cardGenerate].SetActive(true);
}

private void HideAllCards()
{
    foreach (var card in dealtCard)
    {
        card.SetActive(false);
    }
}
}
```

[image]
[image]
Works fine for me:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Could you explain why I needed two populated scripts in this game object?

Comment: No, you only need one, the pictures I show here is to show my testing process (call DealMyNewCard() from context menu ).

Answer (score 1):

Slightly more efficient than the other answers would be handle all in a single loop

```
public void DealMyNewCard()
{
    // btw I would start at 0 if you want to ever get the first item as well
    cardGenerate = Random.Range(0, dealtCard.Length);

    // iterate through the card once
    for(var i = 0; i < dealtCard.Length; i++)
    {
        // set item active if it is the random index otherwise set inactive
        dealtCard[i].SetActive(i == cardGenerate);
    }
}
```

---

alternatively I would actually suggest to rather store the current active card and do not iterate at all:

```
private GameObject currentCard;

private void Awake()
{
    // Initially deactivate all ONCE
    foreach (var card in dealtCard)
    {
        card.SetActive(false);
    }
}

public void DealMyNewCard()
{
    // if there is a current card
    if(currentCard)
    {
        // disable that one - no other card should be active anyway
        currentCard.SetActive(false);
    }

    cardGenerate = Random.Range(0, dealtCard.Length);
 
    // store the new card and enable it
    currentCard = dealtCard[cardGenerate];
    currentCard.SetActive(true);
}
```

This way you could even make sure you don't get the same card twice e.g. using a little Linq magic

```
using System.Linq;

...

currentCard = dealtCard.Where(c => c != currentCard).OrderBy(c => Random.value).First();
urrentCard.SetActive(true);
```

---

OR even better, do it like in real live, shuffle the deck ONCE at the beginning and then actually deal card from it one by one without duplicates

```
public GameObject[] dealtCard;

private IEnumerator<GameObject> shuffledCards;
private GameObject currentCard;

private void Awake()
{
    // Initially deactivate all ONCE
    foreach (var card in dealtCard)
    {
        card.SetActive(false);
    }

    // order cards randomly and store es enumerator
    shuffledCards = dealtCard.OrderBy(c => UnityEngine.Random.value).GetEnumerator();
}

public void DealMyNewCard()
{
    // if there is a current card
    if (currentCard)
    {
        // disable that one - no other card should be active anyway
        currentCard.SetActive(false);
    }

    // try to move to the next card
    // if this returns falls you reached the end of the deck
    if (!shuffledCards.MoveNext())
    {
        Debug.LogError("No more cards available!");
        return;
    }

    // store the new card and enable it
    currentCard = shuffledCards.Current;
    currentCard.SetActive(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about hide all cards before showing the dealt card? like:

```
public void DealMyNewCard()
{

   cardGenerate = Random.Range(2, 6);
   HideAllCards();
   dealtCard[cardGenerate].SetActive(true);
}

private void HideAllCards()
{
      foreach (var card in dealtCard)
      {
           card.SetActive(false);
      }
}
```

A more elegant way to show only one card at a time is using only one card game object in the hierarchy, and set it look each time you pick up a random card. Doing this way, you don't need to call `SetActive()` multiple times when dealting new card.

Comment: Does this suggest having a second button for calling hide all cards function?

Comment: No, there is no button setup in the above code, the `HideAllCards` method just get called before the dealt card being set active.

Comment: For some reason this is throwing UnassignedReferenceException: The variable dealtCard of DealCard has not been assigned.

Comment: You need to assign `dealtCard` from Inspector.

Comment: It is still spawning multiple cards on the scene without removing any of the previous.

Comment: Did you assign all card game object to `dealtCard` from the inspector?
Wheare do you call the `DealMyNewCard()` method?

Comment: I assigned deal card script to the "settings" object and from then I assigned all the card elements.